# Yodlee Instant Account Verification API

Tags: yodlee

How to verify a bank account through Yodlee IAV, without providing account number and routing number ?
Is there any means to verify by prompting for netbanking credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yodlee IAV data services for the same, while you can skip the first step where you'll ask consumer to enter the RTN and directly ask them to first choose the bank site and then check if IAV is supported for that particular site or not. You can find the Yodlee IAV data services flow chart over [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification_API/IAV_Services_Guide/IAV_API_Flow/IAV_Data_Services_API_Flow).